# How do you make a changing background in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to make my application change background pictures every now and then but I can't get the pictures to load. I used Inspect Element and I don't get any 404 for my pictures but rails seems to not be able to load them.
Anyway here is my code so far. For now it just fades in and out the whole screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var backgrounds = ["medium2-doge-hannibal.jpg", "dog_bone_wide.jpg", "water_sports_medium.jpg"];

    function nextBackground() {

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgrounds.length);
        $(".public-content").fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(".public-content").css("background", "asset-path("+backgrounds[rand]+" )");
            $(".public-content").fadeIn(300, function () {
                setTimeout(nextBackground, 3000)
            });
        });
    }
    nextBackground();
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `asset-path` is evaluated when your assets are compiled.  With that, the solution to your issue is to move the call to `asset-path` to the `backgrounds` array.

Comment: @jvnill Thanks but how would I go about doing that?

var backgrounds = ["asset-path('medium2-doge-hannibal.jpg')", "asset-path('dog_bone_wide.jpg')", "asset-path('water_sports_medium.jpg')"];

this didn't work.

Comment: check the compiled javascript code.  what does the `backgrounds` variable evaluate to if you look at it in the developer tools?  once you figure out how to fill that array up, you'll be able to figure your answer out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jvnill` is right.

You'll need to [append the `.erb` filetype](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb) to your js:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
function nextBackground() {
    var backgrounds = ["<%= asset_path('medium2-doge-hannibal.jpg') %>", "<%= asset_path('dog_bone_wide.jpg') %>", "<%= asset_path('water_sports_medium.jpg') %>"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgrounds.length);

    $(".public-content").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(".public-content").css("background", backgrounds[rand]);
        $(".public-content").fadeIn(300, function () {
            setTimeout(nextBackground, 3000)
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   nextBackground();
});
```

Comment: Thanks again @Rich Peck this worked. I just had to add "url(" within the jquery that adds the css, so that line ended up looking like this:  $(".public-content").css("background", "url(" +backgrounds[rand] +")no-repeat center center");